# Is the Scalar Product Definition in my book wrong?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In Rainer Kress'es book "linear integral equations" (2nd edition) on page 9 it says

> **Definition 1.19** Let X be a complex (or real) linear space. Then a function $(\cdot , \cdot): \rightarrow X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\; (or \mathbb{R})$ with the properties.
>   (H1) $(\varphi, \varphi) \geq 0 $ (positivity)
>   [...].
>   for all $\varphi \in X$ is called a Scalar product.

Now, if the mapping goes from $X\times X$ to $\mathbb{C}$, we might have to compare imaginary numbers with the > relation, which is not possible to my knowledge.
Is this a mistake in the book, or did I miss something?

Edit: pardon my formatting, I'm typing this on my phone

**Clarification**
Why do we map $X \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in the first place if we implicitly assume it is real anyway. I find this confusing.

**Result**
My confusion came from, that I thought of a mapping to be a  Scalar product which turned out it was not.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Without context, it is difficult to say if there may have been a mistake. However, if done correctly, one of the other properties of $(\cdot, \cdot)$ will be the fact that $(\phi, \psi) = \overline{(\psi,\phi)}$, where the line denotes complex conjugation. In particular, you have that $(\phi,\phi) = \overline{(\phi,\phi)}$ and thus $(\phi, \phi)$ is always real.

Alternatively, for complex numbers $\alpha$, you could interpret $\alpha \geq 0$ as meaning "$\alpha$ is real, and furthermore $\alpha \geq 0$".

Comment: Yes, that is also mentioned. However, why do we map $X \times X$ to $\mathbb{C}$ in the first place, if we assume the result to be always real?

Comment: Note that $(\phi, \psi)$ need not (and will not) be real in general. Only when $\phi = \psi$, i.e. for $(\phi, \phi)$, the argument above works.

Comment: In particular, if $(\phi, \phi) \neq 0$, then $(\phi, \phi)$ is a positive real number, and therefore -- by one of the other properties of $(\cdot, \cdot)$ -- you will have that $(i\phi, \phi) = i(\phi,\phi) \notin \mathbb R$.

Comment: Ah. I think I got this. Let $\varphi=1+i$. Then $f(a, b) = a*b$ with $a=b=\varphi$  yields $2i$ thus $f$ does not define a Scalar product?

Comment: You mean in the case when $X = \mathbb C$ as a vector space over $\mathbb C$? Note that, in that case, $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is *not* given by multiplication: $(\phi, \psi) \neq \phi \times \psi$ (in general) but instead $(\phi, \psi) = \phi \times \overline{\psi}$. So if we take $\phi = 1 + i$, then $(1 + i, 1 + i) = (1+i)(1-i) = 2$, and $i(1 + i, 1 + i) = (-1 + i, 1 + i) = (-1 + i)(1 - i) = 2i$.

Comment: Please see my updated comment. I sent too early

Comment: Yes, that is correct -- that proves that $f$ does not define a scalar product. You can check by hand that at least two axioms fail: we have $f(i, i) = -1 < 0$, and we also have $f(1, i) = i \neq -i = \overline{f(i, 1)}$.

Answer (score 4):

It is correct, because the only elements of $\mathbb C$ for which the relation $\geq$ is defined are real numbers. Therefore, the statement $$z\in\mathbb C\land z \geq 0$$ is equivalent to the statement $$z\in\mathbb R \land z\geq 0.$$

---

We do not implicitly assume that the mapping is real. We only assume that $(\phi, \phi)$ is real for all values of $\phi$, not that $(\phi, \psi)$ is real for all values of $\phi,\psi$.

For example, the mapping $$(.,.):\mathbb C^2\to \mathbb C\\ (z,w)\mapsto z\cdot \overline w$$

is a scalar product, and $(z,z)$ is always real, however $(i,1)$ is **not** real.

Answer (score 1):

It follows implicitly that $(\phi,\phi)$ must be a real number *and* be $\ge 0$ at the same time. This is implicit here. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Complex_coordinate_space) is a bit more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

A scalar product is, as the name implies, a product whose result is a scalar. If X is a complex linear space, then the space of scalars will be the complex numbers, so the scalar product will map to the complex numbers. So the codomain of the scalar product will be the set of complex numbers, even though the range will be positive real numbers for a vector with itself.

Comment: What do you even mean by "codomain" vs "range" here? In fact, as 5xum points out, the image of a scalar product on complex vector spaces will include non-real values. When taking the product of a vector *with itself*, you will always get a positive real number. But when taking the scalar product of two different vectors, there is no such restriction.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The codomain is the "type" of the output, while the range is the set of outputs. When you take the dot product of a vector with itself, the output "lives in" the field of complex numbers, even though it's a real number.

Comment: There are two meanings commonly given to the word "range" - one is the codomain, the other is the image - the set of all values taken on. Your post is false under both meanings - the image and codomain are both all of $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, I've edited my answer. For vectors without themselves, the codomain is complex, but the range is real.